# Getting User Input from a Text File in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-input

I have a Pandas program ready to take user inputs to form relevant dataframes. However, the user inputs now don't come from the user's keyboard but from another text file instead. The text file looks like the following:

```
3
16SCSE102014
15/03/19
16SCSE101350
15/03/19
16SCSE101002
22/03/19
```

As you can see its just a few strings of input data that were otherwise to come directly from the users keyboard. The long numbers are Registration Numbers to be entered at the input prompt, and the dates are the dates that are to be entered to fetch a particular record.

However, the topmost number in the text file is also a user input which will decide how many records are to be fetched by the user in a single run of the program. (In this example case, it's 3 times. And hence 3 record pairs of regno and date are provided). There can be other text files with top number n, followed by equal number of user input data pairs like above.

So far,

```
with open(rpath_2, 'r') as f:
    cont = f.read().splitlines()
print(cont)
```

is returning a list that reads

```
['3', '16SCSE102014', '15/03/19', '16SCSE101350', '15/03/19', '16SCSE101002', '22/03/19']
```

How can I turn this list into my required user input to build the needed dataframe to fetch the records? The program must hold true for 'n' records not just this example of '3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> cont = ['3', '16SCSE102014', '15/03/19', '16SCSE101350', '15/03/19', '16SCSE101002', '22/03/19']
>>> record_length = 2
>>> for i in range(1, record_length * int(cont[0]), record_length):
...    # print records
...    print(cont[i:(i+record_length)])

['16SCSE102014', '15/03/19']
['16SCSE101350', '15/03/19']
['16SCSE101002', '22/03/19']
```

And if you change the first value in `cont` for 5 the list should return empty lists:

```py
>>>cont = ['5', '16SCSE102014', '15/03/19', '16SCSE101350', '15/03/19', '16SCSE101002', '22/03/19']
>>> for i in range(1, record_length * int(cont[0]), record_length):
...    # print records
...    print(cont[i:(i+record_length)])

['16SCSE102014', '15/03/19']
['16SCSE101350', '15/03/19']
['16SCSE101002', '22/03/19']
[]
[]
```

Comment: Hi Gustavo, your logic is irrefutable. But I still can't seem to get how to assign these to a variable that would otherwise be the result of a user input. Ex: input regno = a[0][0] and input date = a[0][1]. Assigning this way would result in a list with same reg and dates. But I want regno and date to be assigned the next pair instead.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what you need? I did not understand it.

Comment: I kinda got it after hours of knocking my head around. Thanks for the help, I used your code in various ways.